# Sending String and Hex data using RS232 VB.net

Tags: vb.net, com, serial-port

I have been developing a program which communicates with a COM device (Fluke 123 Scopemeter).  When I am sending over ASCII data, I have had no issues.

What I need to do is send over a combination of ASCII and HEX data.  I've been looking at a number of posts on this site, but they seem to be focussed on exclusively sending HEX data.  I need to find a way of sending combined ASCII and HEX - essentially, I need to find a way to effectively format the HEX data so it is understood by the COM device.

An example of how I've been building my string follows.  It gives me an error "Conversion from string PS #0x" to type 'Double' is not valid" which I'm assuming is because I'm mixing two data types!  I hope I'm doing something really silly and this is actually straightforward!

```
'Building my command line
Command = "PS"
Command += ControlChars.Cr
Command += "#0 x"
Command += &H0 + &H2 + &H0 + &H0 + &H0
Command += " y"
Command += &H0 + &H1 + &H0 + &H0

...

'Writing my command to the COM device
moRS232.Write(Command)
```

Any help anyone can give would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to send bytes, which means that your strings need to be converted to bytes.  An example:

```
    Dim buf As New List(Of Byte)
    buf.AddRange(moRS232.Encoding.GetBytes("PS" & ControlChars.Cr & "#0 x"))
    buf.AddRange(New Byte() {0, 2, 0, 0, 0})
    buf.AddRange(moRS232.Encoding.GetBytes(" y"))
    buf.AddRange(New Byte() {0, 1, 0, 0})
    moRS232.Write(buf.ToArray, 0, buf.Count)
```

Do you have a manual that shows the protocol?  If you paste a link.

Comment: This was the code that I based my COM communication on.  [Serial Communication with VB.Net](http://www.codeworks.it/net/VBNetRs232.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You are right - it will get very confusing for the Fluke if it gets both ascii and hex data [even if it were possible to send in one method].

So, if the Write method needs a string, then you need to convert your hex commands to a string as well see the ASC() / CHR() commands